# Windows Server 2012 WSFC and NLB together

Tags: windows-server-2012, load-balancing, cluster

I am looking to run a combination of WSFC and NLB in my service
stack. I have a stateless service that I want to load-balance with NLB, and several "singleton" services that need to be run with fail-over clustering as they are stateful and cannot be run in N+1 configuration.

Say I have a pool of 3 Windows Server 2012 instances to work with. Is it possible to configure these to simultaneously support NLB for the stateless service and WSFC for the stateful services?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not supported on the same box.

The reason why is that when you install the Failover Clustering feature, it adds in the networking stack NetFT.sys the fault tolerant networking adapter for inter-node communication. Network Load Balancing is not aware of this, and traffic cannot be routed/load-balanced properly.

You should probably think about using a hardware load balancer (F5...) in front of the cluster.

Regards.